# Problems installing Nvidia drivers for CUDA on Rocky Linux 9 - modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': Key was rejected by service

Tags: nvidia, rocky-linux

I've just installed the Nvidia drivers using the instructions here on our Threadripper workstations, https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#rhel-9-rocky-9

However, I'm getting this error after a reboot

modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': Key was rejected by service

```
[root@athos ~]# nvidia-smi                                                                                               
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                         
[root@athos ~]# modprobe nvidia                                 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': Key was rejected by service
```

I imagine I could turn off secure boot, but that seems rather inelegant and I would rather solve the problem properly.

Any advice or suggestions, would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to disable secure boot, reboot your machine, and tried again?

#check the black list

sudo grep blacklist /etc/modprobe.d/* /lib/modprobe.d/* | grep nvidia

## comment the following line on this file /lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-kms.conf:

nvidia-drm modeset=1

sudo mokutil --disable-validation

and at the boot, you will see a prompt where you will disable secure boot, and after you boot again, try the modprobe command again.

I hope this helps.